# 'Project1.Player' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Tags: c#, serialization, stream

I am learning some C# by improving an open source C# text-based adventure. I am working on saving all the player data to a file and loading it.

When I try to serialize my player class, the compiler throws the error:

```
'Project1.Player' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable' Program.cs:72
```

**UPDATED**
Ok to make things easier, I updated all my code to its current state.
The new error I am getting every time I reference player is:
`The name 'player' does not exist in the current context`

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace Project1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int windowWidth = 80;
        public static int windowHeight = 35;
        public static bool run = true;
        public static string errorMessage;
        public static bool isError = false;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // setup console window
            Console.Clear(); 
            // set size
            Console.SetWindowSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
            // remove scroll bar with buffer size equal to window size
            Console.BufferWidth = windowWidth;
            Console.BufferHeight = windowHeight;

            // generate world
            Player player = new Player();
            World.GenerateWorld();

            // begin character creation
            string name = Text.Prompt("Welcome stranger.  What is your name?");
            player.name = name;
            player.inventory.Add(new Item("Candle", "A single white candle.", 22));

            Text.WriteLine("Thanks, " + name);
            Text.WriteLine("Press any key to get started.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
            Text.WriteLine("The last thing you remember is battling the Ancient LichLord deep within a cavern beneath Death Mountain.   Now suddenly, you are surrounded by the darkness of true night as you stand in front of an ancient stone castle of complex architecture.  Looking up, you notice the faint glow of a light coming from an old clock tower, high above the castle.  The doors to the castle are large and covered in an ancient mold. Unsure of what to do, you drag open the large wooden door, light the candle you found in your pocket, and step into the castle. \n \nPress a key...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();

            while (run)
            {
                if (!isError)
                {
                    Text.SetPrompt();
                    World.LocationDescription();

                    string temp = Text.Prompt("");
                    Console.Clear();
                    player.Do(temp);
                }
                // there is an error
                else
                {
                    DisplayError();
                }
            }
        }

        // stream writer to write to file.
        public static void SaveGame()
        {
            try
            {
                using (Stream stream = File.Open("save.dat", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                    bin.Serialize(stream, player);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
            }
        }

        public static void LoadGame()
        {
            if (File.Exists("save.dat"))
            {
                try
                {
                using (Stream stream = File.Open("save.dat", FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
                        var player = bin.Deserialize(stream);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Program.SetError("The savegame does not exist!");
            }
        }
        // stream reader to find file
        //public static void LoadGame()
        //{
        //    try
        //    {
        //        using (Stream stream = File.Open("data.bin", FileMode.Open))
        //        {
        //            BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
        //            World.map = (List<Location>)bin.Deserialize(stream);
        //        }
        //    }
        //    catch (IOException)
        //    {
        //    }
        //}

        public static void WinGame()
        {
            run = false;
            Text.WriteLine("As you place the crown upon your head, your vision begins to blur and you fall to the floor.   You wake up in a hot cavern, lit by a few torches on the wall.  This is the cavern of the Ancient LichLord, and you have escaped his twisted maze. ");
        }

        #region Error Handling
        public static void SetError(string aText)
        {
            isError = true;
            errorMessage = aText;
        }

        public static void UnsetError()
        {
            isError = false;
            errorMessage = "";
        }

        public static void DisplayError()
        {
            Text.WriteColor("|r|" + errorMessage + "|g|");
            Text.BlankLines(2);
            UnsetError();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Player.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace Project1
{
    [Serializable()]
    class Player
    {
        public string name;
        //public static string desc;
        //public static int[] stats;
        public int location;
        public List<Item> inventory = new List<Item>();
        public string[] possibleActions = new string[] { "move", "m", "look", "l", "take", "t", "drop", "d", "use", "u", "inventory", "i", "help", "h", "quit", "exit", "save", "load", "name" };

        /// <summary>
        /// Player action, array of predicate and target
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="aAction"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public void Do(string aText)
        {
            string verb = "";
            string noun = "";

            // check if there is a space in the given command
            if (aText.IndexOf(' ') != -1)
            {
                // split the string into the verb and noun
                string[] temp = aText.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2);
                verb = temp[0].ToLower();
                noun = temp[1].ToLower();
            }
            else
            {
                // verb only
                verb = aText.ToLower();
            }

            if (IsAction(verb))
            {
                // do whatever action
                switch (verb)
                {
                    case "move":
                    case "m":
                        if (noun == "")
                            Program.SetError("You must specify a location to move.");
                        else
                            MoveTo(noun);
                        break;

                    case "look":
                    case "l":
                        if (noun == "")
                            noun = World.map[player.location].name;

                        LookAt(noun);
                        break;

                    case "take":
                    case "t":
                        if (noun == "")
                            Program.SetError("You must specify an item to take.");
                        else
                            PickUpItem(noun);
                        break;

                    case "drop":
                    case "d":
                        if (noun == "")
                            Program.SetError("You must specify an item to drop.");
                        else
                            DropItem(noun);
                        break;

                    case "use":
                    case "u":
                        if (noun == "")
                            Program.SetError("You must specify an item to use.");
                        else
                            UseItem(noun);
                        break;

                    case "inventory":
                    case "i":
                        ListInventory();
                        break;

                    case "help":
                    case "h":
                        ListActions();
                        break;

                    case "quit":
                    case "exit":
                        QuitPrompt();
                        break;

                    case "save":
                        Program.SaveGame();
                        break;

                    case "load":
                        Program.LoadGame();
                        break;
                    case "name":
                        Console.WriteLine("Your name is {0}", player.name);
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // not a real action
                Program.SetError("Action not found.");
            }
        }

        public void MoveTo(string location)
        {
            // is location?
            if (World.IsLocation(location))
            {
                int locationId = World.GetLocationIdByName(location);

                if (World.IsLocationExit(location))
                {
                    // set the player's new location
                    player.location = locationId;
                }
                else
                {
                    Program.SetError("You can't get there from here.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Program.SetError("That is not a real location.");
            }
        }

        public void LookAt(string noun)
        {
            // is location?  
            if (World.IsLocation(noun))
            {
                Console.Clear();
                World.ShowHiddenItems();
                Text.BlankLines(2);
            }
            // is item?
            else if (Item.IsItemInInventory(noun) || Item.IsItemInLocation(noun))
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Text.WriteLine(Item.GetItemDescByName(noun));
                Text.BlankLines(2);
            }
        }

        public void PickUpItem(string item)
        {
            // is item?
            if (Item.IsItemInLocation(item))
            {
                // get description
                string desc = Item.GetItemDescByName(item);
                int actionLocationId = Item.GetItemActionLocationIdByName(item);
                // remove item from location
                Item.RemoveItemFromLocation(item);
                // add item to inventory
                player.inventory.Add(new Item(item, desc, actionLocationId));
            }
            else
            {
                Program.SetError("Item not found in this location.");
            }
        }

        public void DropItem(string item)
        {
            //is item?
            if (Item.IsItemInInventory(item))
            {
                string desc = Item.GetItemDescByName(item);
                int actionLocationId = Item.GetItemActionLocationIdByName(item);

                // remove item from inventory
                RemoveInventoryItem(item);

                // add item to location
                World.map[player.location].items.Add(new Item(item, desc, actionLocationId));
            }
            else
            {
                Program.SetError("Item not in inventory.");
            }
        }

        public void RemoveInventoryItem(string item)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < player.inventory.Count; i++)
            {
                if (player.inventory[i].name.ToLower() == item.ToLower())
                {
                    player.inventory.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }

        public void UseItem(string item)
        {
            // is item?
            if (Item.IsItemInInventory(item))
            {
                // get item actionLocationId
                int itemActionLocationId = Item.GetItemActionLocationIdByName(item);
                if (itemActionLocationId == player.location)
                {
                    World.UseItemInLocation(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    Program.SetError("You're not sure how that helps here.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Program.SetError("Item not in inventory");
            }
        }

        public void ListInventory()
        {
            Text.WriteLine("\n-- Inventory -- \n");

            for (int i = 0; i < player.inventory.Count; i++)
            {
                Text.WriteLine(i.ToString() + ": "+ player.inventory[i].name);
            }

            Text.BlankLines(2);
        }

        public void ListActions()
        {
            Text.BlankLines(2);

            //"move", "look", "take", "drop", "use", "inventory", "help"
            Text.WriteLine("\n-- Actions -- \n");
            Text.WriteLine("move - travel to another location.   usage: move entrance hall (or) m entrance hall");
            Text.WriteLine("look - look at a location or an item.   usage: look entrance hall (or) look sword (or) l entrance hall (or) l sword");
            Text.WriteLine("take - pick up an item in a location.   usage: take sword (or) t sword");
            Text.WriteLine("drop - drop an item from your inventory.   usage: drop sword (or) d sword");
            Text.WriteLine("use - use an item in your inventory.   usage: use key (or) u key");
            Text.WriteLine("inventory - show items in your inventory.   usage: inventory (or) i");
            Text.WriteLine("help - show this screen.   usage: help (or) h");
            Text.WriteLine("exit - quit the game.    usage: quit (or) exit");

            Text.BlankLines(2);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check the legitmacy of the action
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="aText"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool IsAction(string aText)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < possibleActions.Length; i++)
            {
                if (aText == possibleActions[i])
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void QuitPrompt()
        {
            Text.WriteLine("Are you sure you want to leave?  y/n");
            string answer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            if (answer == "y" || answer == "yes")
            {
                Program.run = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Item.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Project1
{
    class Item : Entity
    {
        public bool isHidden = false;
        public int actionLocationId;
        public string actionName;

        public Item(string aName, string aDesc, int aActionLocationId, bool aIsHidden = false, string aActionName = "use")
            :base(aName, aDesc)
        {
            actionLocationId = aActionLocationId;
            actionName = aActionName;

            if (aIsHidden)
                isHidden = aIsHidden;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Looks for item in player.inventory
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="aName">name of the Item</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool IsItemInInventory(string aName)
        {
            // look for item in inventory
            for (int i = 0; i < player.inventory.Count; i++)
            {
                if (player.inventory[i].name.ToLower() == aName.ToLower())
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            // not found
            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Looks for item in current location
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="aName">name of the Item</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool IsItemInLocation(string aName)
        {
            // look for item in location
            for (int i = 0; i < World.map[player.location].items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (World.map[player.location].items[i].name.ToLower() == aName.ToLower())
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            // not found
            return false;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Items are only items if in player.inventory or player.location
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="aName">name of the Item</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetItemDescByName(string aName)
        {
            // look for item in location
            for (int i = 0; i < World.map[player.location].items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (World.map[player.location].items[i].name.ToLower() == aName.ToLower())
                {
                    return World.map[player.location].items[i].description;
                }
            }

            // look for item in inventory
            for (int i = 0; i < player.inventory.Count; i++)
            {
                if (player.inventory[i].name.ToLower() == aName.ToLower())
                {
                    return player.inventory[i].description;
                }
            }

            // not found
            return "Item not found";
        }

        public static int GetItemActionLocationIdByName(string aName)
        {
            // look for item in inventory
            for (int i = 0; i < player.inventory.Count; i++)
            {
                if (player.inventory[i].name.ToLower() == aName.ToLower())
                {
                    return player.inventory[i].actionLocationId;
                }
            }

            // look for item in location
            for (int i = 0; i < World.map[player.location].items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (World.map[player.location].items[i].name.ToLower() == aName.ToLower())
                {
                    return World.map[player.location].items[i].actionLocationId;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        public static void RemoveItemFromLocation(string item)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < World.map[player.location].items.Count; i++ )
            {
                if (World.map[player.location].items[i].name.ToLower() == item.ToLower())
                {
                    World.map[player.location].items.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note 3 things:

1. I am learning C#, and I am coming from a JS background.
2. I realize there are some things seriously wrong with how I am trying to save the  player data, but that is why I'm here.
3. This is the first time I've tried saving a large amount of data in a program, so there is a lot of experimentation going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate a `Player` object before you can use it, so this:

```
Player.name = name;
Player.inventory.Add(new Item("Candle", "A single white candle.", 22));
```

Should be something like:

```
var player = new Player();
player.name = name;
player.inventory.Add(new Item("Candle", "A single white candle.", 22));
// etc...
```

Just replace all of your `Player.` calls with `player.` (or whatever you decide to call your player variable) after you instantiate a `Player` object (using the `new` keyword).

**UPDATE**

Your `Player` class is effectively static (meaning there can only be one defined at a time). I'd recommend changing it to something more like:

```
class Player
{
    public string name;
    public int location;
    public List<Item> inventory = new List<Item>();
    public string[] possibleActions = new string[] { "move", "m", "look", "l", "take", "t", "drop", "d", "use", "u", "inventory", "i", "help", "h", "quit", "exit", "save", "load", "name" };

    /// <summary>
    /// Player action, array of predicate and target
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="aAction"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public void Do(string aText)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void MoveTo(string location)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void LookAt(string noun)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void PickUpItem(string item)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void DropItem(string item)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void RemoveInventoryItem(string item)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void UseItem(string item)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void ListInventory()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void ListActions()
    {
        // ...
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check the legitmacy of the action
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="aText"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool IsAction(string aText)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void QuitPrompt()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then if you really only need one global instance of `Player` then define it as static in `Program`:

```
public static Player CurrentPlayer = new Player();
```

If you did it this way then you could access the `Player` instance like:

```
CurrentPlayer.name = name;
CurrentPlayer.inventory.Add(new Item("Candle", "A single white candle.", 22));
```

On the other hand, if it isn't important that you're only working with a single instance of `Player` then you could just remove all of the `static` keywords from your `Player` class. That should allow you to get past your error.

**UPDATE**

My recommended solution from my comment below would look something roughly like (without all of the detail from the code in your question):

```
public class Player
{
    public static Player CurrentPlayer = new Player(); // This is your global instance
    public string name;
    // All of your other content here
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // In here we can access our global instance of `Player` to change it as needed
        Player.CurrentPlayer.name = "Some Name Here";
    }
}
```

After adding the static `CurrentPlayer` field to the `Player` class, you can change all of your references to `player` in all three of your code files to `Player.CurrentPlayer`.

Comment: Doing that now causes this error:
`Member 'Project1.Player.name' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.`

Comment: As the others mention, `Player` likely shouldn't contain static fields and methods. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Now I am getting tons of errors similar to this in my Item.cs (now included in the question). `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Project1.Player.inventory' Item.cs:34`

Comment: You'll need to remove `static` from your methods as well if you expect them to have access to your fields.

Comment: One example: `public static bool IsItemInInventory(string aName)` is still static.

Comment: Oh I thought you were talking about just removing static from my `Player` class. I'll update Item.cs and see how it goes.

Comment: My mistake, I hadn't realized that you had added code from a different class. Though it also probably shouldn't be static.

Comment: I'm guessing you get the error in `SaveGame` and `LoadGame`, that is because `player` is defined in `Main`. Move `Player player = new Player();` out of `Main` (with `windowWidth` and such) and make it static there.

Comment: Nope, still getting the error. It is occurring in Item.cs, World.cs, and Player.cs.

Comment: This is painful. I can tell you why it is happening, but I'm not going to debug your application for you. You could probably benefit from picking up a good book on C# (I hear Jon Skeet's is pretty good). As with JS, variables in C# have scope. One difference is that there really isn't a concept of _global variables_ (in the sense that you define a variable once and it is available throughout all of your code). Quick fix: Add a single static field to your `Player` class that represents your one instance of it and change all of your 'player' variables to `Player.CurrentPlayer`.

Comment: That will work but in reality if it was my project I'd probably scrap the whole thing and start over with good sound OO principles.

Comment: @ryansworld10 - Updated with an example of how this would look.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Sorry it was so frustrating :/

Answer (score 0):

To make your code work, you would have to implement your Player class as static. However, only use [static classes when necessary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Otherwise, you have to create an instance of the Player class to work with it.

```
Player player = new Player();
player.name = name;
....
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message clearly states, you need to put in a variable as a parameter (a instance of a player), not a class, e.g. your player class.

It seems like you have misunderstood the use of classes, as everything in your player class is static, so shared by every instance of the class so instantiating becomes quit useless. If you wish to have only one instance of your player, you should read about the [singleton pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx).

The right way in your example is to remove the static declarations in your player class and initializing a new instance of your player class before using it in your game.

Example:

```
Player p = new Player(); 
p.Name = "Something"
...
try
{
    using (Stream stream = File.Open("save.dat", FileMode.Create))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
        bin.Serialize(stream, p);
    }
}
catch (IOException)
{
}
```